# How to get all the orders as a json in laravel using laravel5 woocommerce api client?

Tags: json, wordpress, laravel, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to get all the order list as a json in laravel using [laravel5-woocommerce-api-client](https://github.com/pixelpeter/laravel5-woocommerce-api-client)
and all i do it is

1.At first run **composer require pixelpeter/laravel5-woocommerce-api-client ^2.0** to my laravel 5.4 project.

2.Second ,Add the **Service Provider** and Add **the Facade**

3.**Publish configuration**

- In this step, Customize configuration, in config/woocommerce.php, i
      updated like this
- 'store_url' => env('WOOCOMMERCE_STORE_URL',
  'http://localhost/ecommerceproject/'),
  http://localhost/ecommerceproject(which is wordpress woocommerce
  url).
- 'consumer_key' => env('WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_KEY',
  'ck_912993d84a43e821628f485a3bd94ad8101612ad'),
- 'consumer_secret' => env('WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_SECRET',
  'cs_b71aebbfcc3cd7365da591a0faa0341a2e689edb'),

And then i created a controller which is PostController and 
put the
 `use Woocommerce;`and 
`public function index(){ return Woocommerce::get('orders'); }`

It show the error like this

> HttpClientException in HttpClient.php line 340:
>   Syntax error

Please guide me where am i missing the steps.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a fresh installation of WooCommerce make sure .htaccess is present and ModRewrite is working.

Check if API URL is working first.